# I want to get two specific directories using getdirectories method

Tags: c#, getdirectories

I want to get two specific directories using getdirectories method in C#? Below is the code for getting one directory:

```
DirectoryInfo sourcefolder = new DirectoryInfo(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SourceLocation"].ToString());s
DirectoryInfo[] sourceRreportSubfolders = sourcefolder.GetDirectories("20120104");
```

With above code I can get directory 20120104, but what If I want to get two directories like (20120104, 20130302)?

Comment: But I want to iterate through this sourceReportSubFolders to process the subfolders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var location = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SourceLocation"].ToString();
DirectoryInfo sourcefolder = new DirectoryInfo(location);
var sourceRreportSubfolders = sourcefolder.GetDirectories("20120104")
                             .Union(sourcefolder.GetDirectories("20130302"));
foreach (var dir in sourceRreportSubfolders)
{
    // Do something with dir
}
```

Comment: you shouldn't do "something" with dir. you should do everything!